# How to embed font style in android mobile?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I develop phonegap application. In my app has two language english and khmer. But my device don't show khmer language. How can I embed font in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your CSS in a file, for example example.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "customfont";
    src: url("./fonts/arial.ttf") format("opentype");   
        /* Make sure you defined the correct path, which is related to
            the location of your file `example.css` */ 
    }
    body {
        font-family: "customfont";
        font-size:30px;
    }
```

-Reference your CSS file example.css in your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/example.css" />
```

Make sure you follow the proper directory structure

For example, let's say you have the following directory structure:

**www**

- example.html

**css**

- example.css

**fonts**

- arial.ttf